# SQL SELECT WHERE field LIKE PHP variable.

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-like

I'm having some trouble using a php variable with an SQL LIKE command. The code below acts as it should. However, if I change `$model = "Cruze Limited";` I don't get any returns from the database. I'm expecting at the very least the same result I'm getting when `$model = "Cruze";` which returns all vehicles that's model contains "Cruze".

I have a feeling I'm just missing some small syntax error but I can't place my finger on it. I apologize in advance if that's the case.

```
<?php 
$make = "Chevrolet";
$model = "Cruze";

$trim = "LT";

$year = '2017';

$query = "SELECT *
          FROM my_table
          WHERE year = '$year'
          AND make = '$make'
          AND model LIKE '$model%'";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
```

<

```
html>
<body>
  <?php while($vehicles = $statement->fetch()): ?>
      <h4><?= $vehicles['year'] ?></h4>
      <h4><?= $vehicles['stock'] ?></h4>
      <h4><?= $vehicles['kms'] ?></h4>
      <h4>$<?= $vehicles['price'] ?></h4>
      <h4><?= $vehicles['make'] ?></h4>
      <h4><?= $vehicles['model'] ?></h4>
      <a href="<?=$vehicles['photos']?>">Photo</a>
  <?php endwhile ?>
<body>
</html>



?>
```

Comment: " I'm expecting at the very least the same result I'm getting when `$model = "Cruze";`" - Well it's not the same.

Comment: `$model%` returns all records that **begins** by `$model`, not "contains".

Comment: A good way to check this is to output the query in some way.  Right after the body tag add `<?= $query; ?>` and that should at least point you in the right direction.  Also, @Syscall is correct, you should use `'%$model%'` instead of `'$model%'`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM my_table
          WHERE year = '$year'
          AND make = '$make'
          AND LOCATE(model,'$model') > 0";
```

Comment: Yep this worked! Thanks!